# doing some of columns based on some complex logic in pyspark

Tags: sql, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[image]

Here is the question in the image attached:

Table:

```
Row Col1    Col2    Col3    Result
1   10       20      100    30
2   20       40      200    60
3   30       60       0     240
4   40       70       0     180
5   30       80      50     110
6   25       35       0      65
7   10       20      60      30
```

So result column is calculated based on the below rules:

1. If col3 >0 , then result=col1+col2
2. If col 3=0, then result= sum (col2) till col3 >0 + col1(where col3>0)

for example for row =3, the result=60+70+80+30(from col1 from row 5 because here col3>0)=240
for row=4, the result=70+80+30(from col1 from row 5 because here col3>0)=180
similarly for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers (correctly, I might add) the original version of the question.

In SQL, you can express this using window functions.  Use a cumulative sum to define the group and the an additional cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (case when col3 <> 0 then col1 + col2
             else sum(col2 + case when col3 = 0 then col1 else 0 end) over (partition by grp order by row desc)
        end) as result
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when col3 <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by row desc) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a5fd1df0b5c124fede4823c977893c60) is a db<>fiddle (which uses Postgres).

Note:

Your description says that the `else` logic should be:

```
else sum(col2) over (partition by grp order by row desc)
```

Your example says:

```
else sum(col2 + col3) over (partition by grp order by row desc)
```

And in my opinion, this seems most logical:

```
else sum(col1 + col2) over (partition by grp order by row desc)
```

Comment: if You see the table for Row 3 we are calculating like this:
since col 3 =0 so it will be sum(col2) till col3>0 so it will eb equal to (60+70+80) and also col1 will be added against col3>0 so the whole sum will be like (60+70+80+50)

Comment: @MradulGupta . . . As the SQL Fiddle shows, the result is exactly what you specify.  The Note is just a comment on the calculation.

Comment: The 50 value you are using for sum will come from col1 not from col3.......this is where difficulty is

Comment: @MradulGupta . . . No, it comes from `col3`.  The expression is `sum(col2 + **col3**) over (partition by grp order by row desc)`

Comment: Yes you are right....you are taking it from col3 ......but I need it from col1.......the Logic is - (once we get the >0 value in col3 then from col1 that value will be used for sum

Comment: @MradulGupta . . . I explained in the extensive note that taking the value from `col3` didn't make sense to me.  Just take it from `col1`.

Comment: But the requirement is like this......50 should come from col1

Comment: @MradulGupta . . . I updated the answer.  You should accept it.