# fetching output from a table based on some conditions using sql,spark

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Table

```
item    value      month     year
A         0          8         2020
B         0          8         2020
A         0          9         2020
B         13          9         2020
A         0          10         2020
B         0          10         2020
A         10          11         2020
B         0          11         2020
A         0          12         2020
B         0          12         2020
A         0          1         2021
B         10          1         2021
A         0          2         2021
B         0          2         2021
A         0          3         2021
B         0          3         2021
A         11          4         2021
B         0          4         2021
```

Output:

```
item  month   year
A      8       2020
A      12       2020
A      1       2021
B      10       2020
B       2       2021
```

rule for the output:
For an item,month,year we need to look for next two months and if the sum(value) for next two months is 0 then it will qualified for output.

For exapmle: for item A month 8 year 2020 sum(value) is 0 till month 10 year 2020.
Similarly for item A month 9 year 2020 sum(value) is ot 0 for next two months so it will not come into output.

Comment: Month 12 of 2020 should be combined with months 1, 2, and 3 from 2021.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

the below answer would be a solution for your scenario,

```
import os
import logging 
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

#input feed
simpleData = [["A",0,8,2020],["B",0,8,2020],["A",0,9,2020],["B",13,9,2020],["A",0,10,2020],["B",0,10,2020],["A",10,11,2020],["B",0,11,2020],["A",0,12,2020],["B",0,12,2020],["A",0,1,2021],["B",10,1,2021],["A",0,2,2021],["B",0,2,2021],["A",0,3,2021],["B",0,3,2021],["A",11,4,2021],["B",0,4,2021]]

#creating a dataframe
cSchema = StructType([StructField("item", StringType()),StructField("value", IntegerType()),StructField("month", IntegerType()),StructField("year", IntegerType())])
df = spark.createDataFrame(simpleData,schema=cSchema)
df.show()

'''
+----+-----+-----+----+
|item|value|month|year|
+----+-----+-----+----+
|   A|    0|    8|2020|
|   B|    0|    8|2020|
|   A|    0|    9|2020|
|   B|   13|    9|2020|
|   A|    0|   10|2020|
|   B|    0|   10|2020|
|   A|   10|   11|2020|
|   B|    0|   11|2020|
|   A|    0|   12|2020|
|   B|    0|   12|2020|
|   A|    0|    1|2021|
|   B|   10|    1|2021|
|   A|    0|    2|2021|
|   B|    0|    2|2021|
|   A|    0|    3|2021|
|   B|    0|    3|2021|
|   A|   11|    4|2021|
|   B|    0|    4|2021|
+----+-----+-----+----+
'''

#registering the dataframe for spark SQL
df.createOrReplaceTempView("input_table");

df1=spark.sql("select * from input_table where item='A'")
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("a_table");
df1=spark.sql("select *,(SUM(value) over ( order by year,month rows between current row and 2 following )- value) sum from a_table")
df1=df1.filter((df1.sum==0) & (df1.value==0))

df2=spark.sql("select * from input_Table where item='B'")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("b_table");
df2=spark.sql("select *,(SUM(value) over ( order by year,month rows between current row and 2 following )- value) sum from b_table")
df2=df2.filter((df2.sum==0) & (df2.value==0))

df1.union(df2).show()
'''
+----+-----+-----+----+---+
|item|value|month|year|sum|
+----+-----+-----+----+---+
|   A|    0|    8|2020|  0|
|   A|    0|   12|2020|  0|
|   A|    0|    1|2021|  0|
|   B|    0|   10|2020|  0|
|   B|    0|    2|2021|  0|
|   B|    0|    3|2021|  0|
|   B|    0|    4|2021|  0|
+----+-----+-----+----+---+
'''
```

Comment: can You plz answer the following qn.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62950700/doing-some-of-columns-based-on-some-complex-logic-in-pyspark

Comment: sure @mradul, please upvote this accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

> For an item,month,year we need to look for next two months and if the sum(value) for next two months is 0 then it will qualified for output.

This sounds like `lead()` or using a window frame:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(value) over (partition by item order by year, month rows between current row and 2 following) as sum_value_3
      from t
     ) t
where sum_value_3;
```

This returns more rows than you specify because your description and desired results are not the same.  You really want the first row in a series of rows where there are 3 *or more* `0` in a row.  One approach to this is as a gap-and-islands problem:

```
select item, year, month, cnt
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by item, seqnum - seqnum_1) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by item, seqnum - seqnum_1 order by year, month) as seqnum_within_group
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by item order by year, month) as seqnum,
                   row_number() over (partition by item, (case when value = 0 then 1 else 0 end) order by year, month) as seqnum_1
            from t
           ) t
      where value = 0
     ) t
where seqnum_within_group = 1 and cnt >= 3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5d815a385a2bc2bccfbc7637ff517c96) is a db<>fiddle, which uses Postgres.